# How to access a ForEach Variable inside an InLineScript within a Workflow?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that connects to several servers and copies a list of text files to a folder on the same server.
What does not work is the script to copy the file to a folder. It seems like the InLineScript could not get a hold of the $File variable, even using $Using:File as I researched.

The errors shows that it is trying to copy the E:\SQL folder instead

> An item with the specified name E:\Logs_2021-06-25\SQL
> already exists.

#List of Servers
ServerList.txt
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3

#List of files to be copied
FileList.txt
file1.log
file2.log
file3.log

```
Workflow LogBackup{
    $ServerList = Get-Content ServerList.txt
    $FileList = Get-Content FileList.txt

    ForEach ($Server in $ServerList) {
        InlineScript {
            #Create a folder named 'Logs_2021-06-25' in E:\Backup on the $Server
            $a = { New-Item -Path "E:\Backup\Logs_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" -ItemType "directory" }
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:Server -ScriptBlock $a
        }
        ForEach ($File in $FileList) {
            InlineScript {
                #Copy each $File to the folder created above
                $b = { Copy-Item "E:\SQL\$Using:File" -Destination "E:\Backup\Logs_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" }
                #It works if I hardcode like so: Copy-Item "E:\SQL\file1.log"
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:Server -ScriptBlock $b
            }
        }
    }
}

LogBackup
```

Comment: If you're using a local variable inside an invoked Scriptblock supply it as an argument - see the -ArgumentList switch for Invoke-Command

Comment: Replace `$using:server` with just `$server`.

Comment: @Scepticalist Okay, I thought $Using should suffice but you are right, I was able to make it work using the ArgumentList switch. I'll post the answer momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work after reading up on the ArgumentList switch as suggested by Scepticalist.

```
ForEach ($File in $FileList) {
    InlineScript {
        $b = { Copy-Item $args[0] -Destination "E:\Backup\Logs_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" }
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:Server -ScriptBlock $b -ArgumentList $Using:File
    }
}
```